# Azure SQL. Move table to "in memory only"

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database

First, I would like to explain a bit the problem:

I have a filtering system which will:

•   Based on different criteria, access rights etc, builds a list of entityA and a list of EntityB. (By ID)

•   Writes thousands of rows in 2 tables (One for EntityA and one for entityB) to be able to perform a join

•   Which allows to get results pretty fast (Azure premium tier helps here) .

•   and then delete the temporary filtering rows. (In both tables)
The “problem” is that Azure SQL, they really take their SLA seriously (Which is good !).

But for these 2 tables, they have more than million writes and deletes per minute. And this data is, how to say it, expendable. Basically, if the whole 2 tables are lost, it would generate at most 3 or 4  exceptions 500 in my web app. (Which I can live with, out of thousands)

But the writes like that trigger Azure SQL a lot and basically the whole database comes to stop due to LogIO (I’m on premium serverless tier with auto scaling from 0.5 vCPU to 9 VCPU). It scales very nicely for all read operations, but these 2 tables are killing all performances.

So I was wondering if there is any way to declare these table “In RAM” or something like “I don’t care if it dies” mode.

(Just in case you are wondering, yes, I tried to use “IN” close. But with more than 10.000 entities in one table and around 2.000 in the second, it just fails. These numbers are PER USER API request)

I found couple of articles here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/defining-durability-for-memory-optimized-objects?view=sql-server-ver15

I never figured how I can migrate already existing table to that mode. Most of links I found starts with “Create a new database”.

I cannot do that at the moment. There are thousands of users per day and our company just cannot have a downtime.

Basically, what I would LOVE is to tell azure sql that I don’t need ANY persistence on these 2 tables. I honestly don’t care if they are wiped out on a glitch. The data here lives only couple of seconds.

Why not use tempdb ? Simply because EntityFramework doesn’t work with temdb and untyped tables. And all attempts I did to use tempDB failed miserably; p

I’m sorry for a long question, but if someone have at least an idea, I’ll gladly take it !

Comment: If you don’t need any persistence, can’t you just keep that data in memory - in your app - and perform whatever operations you need there?

Comment: in-memory tables in SQL aren't really a solution for using a code-first technology in your app-tier.  They are intended for specialized high-end use.  Think "formula 1 car" vs. "normal car" in that most people can't drive an F1 car.  In-memory tables do not easily correct design limitations in the app tier.  So, please consider whether what you have is optimal in the app tier first.  (It is possible to write a reasonably fast EF-app against SQL, but the default is fast to code, not fast to execute.

Comment: @sellotape hello. Unfortunatly no, as they are using for filter other tables via joints.

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT Yes you are right. But in our case, the Formula F1 car is exactlly what we need from theses two tables. These two tables got almost 100.000 inserts and deletes per second. We need these tables to be F1. It may be a design flow in the application, I agree. But that would be the "less effort spent for way better result" solution.